I want to change my custom post url dynamically in WordPress
I have change dynamically url in custom post at wordpress. I have try chnge but maximun times redirect to 404 page. Please help me how to archive that logic. I have describe at below of require details
I have plug in in WordPress. Here in Plug in One custom post that is 'rank_services' and two taxonomy of 'rank_services' these are 'service_category' and 'service_location'. In 'service_location' store term like 'Bhubaneswar', 'Patna', 'Gujurat' etc. and in 'service_category' store like 'AC', 'Microwave Oven ' etc. . In 'rank_services' write a post like title 'Installatin service and repair in', post url like 'installatin-service-and-repair-in'. I have must be select one 'service_category' and multiple select 'service_location'. my create custom post 'rank_services' code is
public function register_rank_services_cpt()
    {
        $args = array(
            'label' => 'Rank Services',
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => true,
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt'),
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-hammer',
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => '',  // This removes 'rank_services' from the URL
                'with_front' => false
            ),
            'has_archive' => false,
        );
        register_post_type('rank_services', $args);
    }

In post url remove 'rank_services' by code is
function advanced_remove_cpt_slug($post_link, $post)
{
    if ('rank_services' === $post->post_type && 'publish' === $post->post_status) {
        // Remove the '/rank_services/' part from the URL
        $post_link = str_replace('/rank_services/', '/', $post_link);
    }
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'advanced_remove_cpt_slug', 10, 2);

function advanced_parse_request($query)
{
    if ($query->is_main_query() && !is_admin()) {
        if (!empty($query->query['name'])) {
            $query->set('post_type', 'rank_services');
        }
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'advanced_parse_request');

Also write code for redirect to single post page that code is
function advanced_rank_services_template_loader($template)
{
    if (is_singular('rank_services')) {
        $custom_template = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'templates/single-rank_services.php';
        if (file_exists($custom_template)) {
            return $custom_template;
        }
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter('template_include', 'advanced_rank_services_template_loader');

After above codeadded then my post url like 'http://localhost/palei/installation-and-repair-service-in/'. So, I want to chang dynamatically my url some condition.
1st condition if click my post url then redirect to 'single-rank_services.php' page with change url like : [term_slug of service_category taxonomy of rank_services post]-[post url]-[term_slug of service_location taxonomy of rank_services post]. I think 'http://localhost/palei/[term_slug of service_category]-installation-and-repair-service-in-[term_slug of service_location]/'. If multiple selected from service_location then add 1st postion term_slug of service_location. After url changes must be redirect to ''templates/single-rank_services.php'' not 404 page. Then lastly i want create short code for fetch service_location term if select multiple term then show changes url with change title. If i have click in list then also redirect to ''templates/single-rank_services.php'' with change url.
